# finding distinct values from the array of documents returned by Mongoose find() query

Tags: javascript, mongoose

The objective is to find distinct values of fields of a Model, from the array of documents retrieved by Mongoose find() query.

Why am I finding distinct: To use these values as filters(options for Select) on the UI.

IMP point to note: The query can return around 10,000+ documents. So performance is also a criteria to select a method.

Here is the Model with the fields for which distinct values are to be found

```
const serviceLogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ....
  calYear: { type: Number, required: true },
  calMonth: { type: Number, required: true },
  FY: { type: String, required: true },
  servStatus: { type: String, required: true },
  servCat: { type: String, required: true },
  dueMonth: {type: String, required: true},
  rm: { type: String },
  compCat: { type: String },
  compGroup: { type: String },
  execName: { type: String },
  approver: { type: String },
  paytStatus: { type: String },
  ...
});
```

Below is the current working method used for each of these fields. But this makes multiple calls on db and hence slows down the process.

```
// this code is repeated for each of the field
  arrCompCat = await ServiceLog.distinct('compCat');
  if(!arrCompCat) {
    arrCompCat = [];
  } else {
    if(arrCompCat.length = 1 && arrCompCat[0] === '') {
      arrCompCat = [];
    } else {
      arrCompCat.sort();
    }
  }
```

On couple of other threads I saw the below method of getting distinct values from an Array.

```
  let arrCompCat = [ ...new Set(fetchedDocs.map(e => e.compCat)) ]
```

But I get the below error.

```
object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

fetchedDocs is the result of the find query. If this were to work it would be a good option as I would retrieve the documents only once from db, and then operate on that array of documents instead of making individual calls to db.

I would use map or filter method but that too could be performance intensive.
is there any performance efficient method for this case?

Comment: If you are worried about performance, you can start improving it by using `.distinct('compCat').lean().exec();`. `lean` returns simple JSON, not Mongoose objects, so it's much lighter and faster. And `exec` returns a true Promise, not an awaitable Promise-like.

Comment: You can use the sort method inside the query: Model.find(filters).sort(sortingMethod).exec(). Also you can put the filters inside the filter object in find. Probably you need to read about queries in mongoose. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html. Here you can find a lot of information that can help you with speed and better practices

Comment: @JeremyThille you actually gave me the solution. I used the lean().exec() method on the query and then i used the  ```let arrCompCat = [ ...new Set(fetchedDocs.map(e => e.compCat)) ]``` method to get the distinct values for each of the fields. Thanks.

Comment: Ah nice :) I have posted my comment as an answer, if it solved your problem could please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about performance, you can start improving it by using `.distinct('compCat').lean().exec();`. [lean](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html) returns simple JSON, not Mongoose objects, so it's much lighter and faster. And [exec](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) returns a true Promise, not an awaitable Promise-like.

Comment: `lean()` has no effect on `distinct()`. It simply returns the plain array passed directly from the driver.